# How to use MapTo Correctly With Sum Types

Tags: scala

I am not sure why the below does not print "It is an A".

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait Foo
case object A extends Foo
case object B extends Foo

val a = Future.successful(A)

a.mapTo[Foo].map {
  case A => println("it is an A")
  case B => println("it is a B")
}.value.get
```

This results in the following:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
... 31 elided
```

I was thinking that I can cast the `A` to a `Foo` with mapTo and then do case analysis over it. This is a simplified version of the problem and program I am working on which uses Akka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask(actor, msg).mapTo[T]` is a [safe way](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/futures.html#use-with-actors) of going from `Future[Any]` to `Future[T]`, and you seem to be using it correctly. The failure is due to `value.get`. Try removing it like so

```
object futureMapToExample extends App {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  sealed trait Foo
  case object A extends Foo
  case object B extends Foo

  val a = Future.successful(A)

  a.mapTo[Foo].map {
    case A => println("it is an A")
    case B => println("it is a B")
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

and it should print

```
it is an A
```

The reason it fails with `value.get` is because `Future` has not yet completed at that point. Note how I added `Thread.sleep(1000)` hack in there to give the `Future` some time to complete. This is just for demonstration purposes and should **not** be done in production. In general `get` calls should be avoided if possible as they are unsafe.

Comment: cool - that works. Basically I have an Akka program and the message it sends back to another actor (in a Future) is of a sum type so I need to get the response from the ask , mapTo the type of the sealed trait and then do case analysis. Is that a valid use of mapTo?

Comment: @Mojo Yes `ask(actor, msg).mapTo[T]` is a safe way of going from `Future[Any]` to `Future[T]`

Comment: Thanks mate - I don't really like Akka. Before I moved to the above solution, I managed to a compile a program where I was sending back a message of type Future[Either[String, Unit]] and then in the receiving actor I did a mapTo to a type of case class Foo(res : Either[String, Unit]] and guess what it compiled!! I am not sure how mapTo was able to cast it to a Foo but I suspect it tried to call the apply method on the case class and do the cast.

Comment: @Mojo Consider [Akka Typed](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/akka-2-5-22-brings-akka-typed-to-production-ready)